# LayoutAnimation on a ListView backed by a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LayoutAnimation defined in XML and set on my ListView XML with android:layoutAnimation, so when the Activity is first created the individual rows animate on layout but when I change the Cursor linked to the CursorAdapter with changeCursor the ListView updates correctly but the rows do not animate.  The Cursor is populated on a background thread (however populating it on the ui thread makes no difference).

How can I get the ListView to run the LayoutAnimation again when the Cursor changes?  I have tried invalidateViews and requestLayout, neither of which work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `ListView` and `CursorAdpater`, it will give you much more control over the layout etc by overriding the necessary methods.

Using `LayoutAnimationController` in code may be preferable to XML `android:layoutAnimation`.